# IMPORTXML Not Pulling Data From Yahoo Finance Statistics Page

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, stock, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to pull stock data from Yahoo Finance, but am unable to pull any data from the Statistics page. This code works fine when pulling from the Summary page, but doesn't seem to work here.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/key-statistics?p=AMD", "//*[@id="Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy"]/section/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its not JavaScript controled you can get it like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/key-statistics?p=AMD", "//tr")
```

[image]